# How to get proper axis tick labels when using sec_axis() and transformation does not start with '~.'

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to create a secondary axis converting from `wavenumber(cm^-1)` to `micrometers(um)`. This transformation takes the form of:

```
x [um] = 10000 / x [cm^-1]
```

When I attempt this using `sec_axis()` the transformation is done correctly, but the axis tick labels are not properly rendered. Using the example code at the end of the post I get the following:

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
  wavenumber = seq(4000, 400, by = -100),
  intensity = runif(37)
)

# Plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = wavenumber, y = intensity)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "Wavenumber (cm^-1)",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 10^4 / ., name="Wavelength (micrometers)")
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

print(p)
```

I tried multiple renditions of the formula and expected a transofmration equivalent to `10000/Original_value` with properly labeled axis ticks, but either got improperly labeled axis ticks or incorrect transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like a problem with the automatic finding of good breaks. I added a specific argument that finds better breaks:

```r
 sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 10^4 / .,
                        name="Wavelength (micrometers)",
                        breaks = scales::breaks_log(n = 6))
```

[image: breaks]

Answer (score 1):

An option using `breaks()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  wavenumber = seq(4000, 400, by = -100),
  intensity = runif(37)
)

# Generate vector of breaks values for plot
plot_breaks <- seq(1000, floor(max(data$wavenumber)), by = 1000)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = data, aes(x = wavenumber, y = intensity)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = plot_breaks,
    name = "Wavenumber (cm^-1)",
    sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = round(10^4 / plot_breaks, 2), 
                        name = "Wavelength (micrometers)")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: result]

Comment: I like this, but I am marking the answer from @uke as accepted since I can automate things a bit more.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, most appreciated. To make it more adaptive, generally what I do is create a vector of breaks for the plot.  I've updated my answer accordingly.